# Python 3.3 Print('string', end='')

Tags: python-3.x

Quick question, is there any difference between these two following bits of code?

Example 1

```
print("hello,", end='')
print(" world")
```

Example 2

```
print ("hello, world")
```

I don't see a difference in output, why would I use one over the other?

Thanks in advance for any answers

Comment: why would you use the first one?

Comment: You wouldnt use the first one. At least not in this case.

Comment: @ Bartlomiej Lewandowski - that was my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would only really use the first one in cases where you may want to keep outputting things onto the same line (think logging something onto one line in a loop for some reason).

Otherwise use the simpler option.

Comment: Both answers equally correct/helpful. Can only give the tick to who got there first I'm afraid. Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

If you use end='' it avoids the newline that python normally inserts in a print statement.

In practice, there's no reason to do it the first way with a short string like that, but if you wanted to put other variables in the output, it could be useful.